# Entity Framework Code First: How to map to stored procedures with less parameters than model properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a model named File with properties CreatedOn and ModifiedOn mapped to columns CreatedOn and ModifiedOn on table File. I don't want values of these columns to be set by users instead, they will be set by using the function GETDATE() in SQL. Following is my code:

This is my model (simplified for test):

```
public class File
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
}
```

My model mapping to stored procedures:

```
public class FileMap: EntityTypeConfiguration<File>
{
    public FileMap()
    {
        MapToStoredProcedures(s => s.Insert(i => i.HasName("InsertFile").Parameter(f => f.Name, "Name")));
    }
}
```

My migration:

```
public partial class AddInsertStoredProcedure: DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateStoredProcedure(
            "dbo.InsertFile",
            p => new
            {
                Name = p.String(),
            },
            body:
                @"INSERT [dbo].[Files]([CreatedOn], [ModifiedOn], [Name])
                  VALUES (GETDATE(), GETDATE(), @Name)

                  DECLARE @Id int
                  SELECT @Id = [Id]
                  FROM [dbo].[Files]
                  WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()

                  SELECT t0.[Id]
                  FROM [dbo].[Files] AS t0
                  WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND t0.[Id] = @Id"
            );
     /* ... */
}
```

My test class:

```
   class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var context = new EntityContext();
        context.Files.Add(new File { Name = "File 1" });
        context.Files.Add(new File { Name = "File 2" });
        context.Files.Add(new File { Name = "File 3" });
        context.Files.Add(new File { Name = "File 4" });
        context.SaveChanges();
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

When running it I receive an exception {"Procedure or function InsertFile has too many arguments specified."}. It seems that EF passed all the properties of my model to the stored procedure InsertFile so there were extra arguments. Can I have EF pass only the property Name?

Comment: Everything looks fine to me but here: MapToStoredProcedures(s => s.Insert(i => i.HasName("InsertFile").Parameter(f => f.Name, "Name"))); you don't need to name the parameter to "Name" as it is already Name so I would remove the parameter. How do you know that EF is passing all of the parameters ? Do you have the SQL output ?

Comment: Very nice question, I will be following this, just out of interest... what does the select stuff do... inside the body section? cant see what its there... is it for when you were debugging in SQL.

Comment: No, I don't know that EF is passing all the parameters. I just guess so throught the exception message content. I can't debug into the SaveChangeds() method of the context object so I can't know exactly where the problem is. The program is broken at context.SaveChanges() with a DbUpdateException

Comment: try putting a try/catch on the savechanges and loop through the entity errors.../?

Comment: I assume you have declared the table File  field id as Key and auto gen in your mapping config classes? also it wouldn't make sense for this to be null-able....

Comment: Just stumbled upon this and want to add a little hint regarding EF SQL debugging: set `DbContext.Database.Log` action to some logging function and inspect the SQL that is generated for the requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding attributes to your properties, if you don't need them in the stored procedure:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```

If you want to get your properties from the stored procedure use:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
```

and map in Fluent.api like this :

```
    public FileMap()
    {
        MapToStoredProcedures(s => s.Insert(i => i.HasName("InsertFile").Parameter(f => f.Name, "Name").Result(f => f.ModifiedOn,"ModifiedOn"));
}
```

For example, this is what I'm using for this:

model:

```
public partial class Order
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int MasterFID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public string Number { get; set; }

    public int? OutletID { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public decimal? Sum { get; set; }
```

Fluent.Api Mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                .MapToStoredProcedures(sp =>
                {
                    sp.Insert(i => i.HasName("web_DS_Set_DocHeaders")
                                    .Parameter(p => p.OutletID, "mfID")
                                    .Parameter(p => p.DocTypeID, "orType")
                                    .Parameter(p => p.Comment, "orComment")
                                    .Parameter(p => p.Sum, "orSum")

                                    .Result(r => r.Number, "orNumber")
                                    .Result(r => r.OrderDate,"orDate")
                                    .Result(r => r.ID, "orID"));
                });
```

And at the end of my stored procedure, I have something like this for return inserted row:

```
Select orNumber, orDate, orId from Orders where --parameters for last inserted|updated row
```